# Using PHP, how do I "Insert and move files between folders" from Google Cloud Platform to Google Drive?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

Using the Google Cloud Platform I want to complete the steps outlined on the following web page, https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder

```
$folderId = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1TGRPeTVjaWRDY1E';
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'photo.jpg',
    'parents' => array($folderId)
));
$content = file_get_contents('files/photo.jpg');
$file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
    'data' => $content,
    'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
    'uploadType' => 'multipart',
    'fields' => 'id'));
printf("File ID: %s\n", $file->id);
```

I have the Drive API enabled and it says I don't need any special credentials since I'm already in Google Cloud Platform. When I run the above code, I get the following error,

```
Fatal error: Class 'Google_Service_Drive' not found
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your whole script, for example, is this information useful for your situation? https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php

Answer (score 2):

The error you’re getting it’s because somehow the Google library (which has the Google_Service_Drive class) is not imported.

Be sure you’re doing the step 2 (Installing Google Library) in the quickstart successfully [1]. Or you could manually download the library to your working directory [2].

Also, be sure you have this line in the beginning of your code (It’ll import all the classes):

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

I reproduced and tested the following code using your code together with the quickstart and worked fine (It gives the same error as your code if i delete the Google Library):

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('G Suite Directory API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes([Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE]);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);


    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));


        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);

        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));

    return $client;
}


$client = getClient();
$driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$folderId =’XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX’;
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'photo.jpg'
    'parents' => array($folderId)
));
$content = file_get_contents('Moon.jpg');
$file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
    'data' => $content,
    'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
    'uploadType' => 'multipart',
    'fields' => 'id'));
printf("File ID: %s\n", $file->id);
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php

[2] https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/releases

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue. Thanks to the other poster as well.